# ¿Cómo hago para cortar una cadena string, en base al identificador 15 en Java?

Tags: java

Por ejemplo tengo:

```
String cadena = "Me_gusta_programar_en_java_y_basededatos.";
```

Perdon la cadena debe mostrarse asi:

```
mar_en_java_y_basededatos. progra_gusta_Me
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes. Te recomiendo completar el [tour] de bienvenida para que entiendas qué tipo de preguntas son bien recibidas y qué se debe aportar al realizarlas. Tu pregunta actual no demuestra ningún intento por tu parte de resolver el problema y las cuestiones del tipo "hacedme los deberes" no están aceptadas a menos que muestres qué has intentado y dónde te has atascado

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Para extraer las partes que te interesan de la cadena puedes usar el método `substring` de la clase `String`. Luego, puedes usar el método `reverse` de la clase `StringBuilder` para darle la vuelta a la cadena que hará de final (antes deberás importar la clase con `import java.util.*`) .

```
String cadena = "Me_gusta_programar_en_java_y_basededatos.";
StringBuilder finCadena = new StringBuilder(cadena.substring(0, 15));
String cadenaModificada = cadena.substring(15) + " " + finCadena.reverse();
System.out.println(cadenaModificada);
```

**Con arrays (editado)**

Crea los dos arrays de carácteres y los llenas con bucles for. Luego, puedes usar el constructor de la clase `Sting` que recibe un array de carácteres para crear la nueva cadena.

```
String cadena = "Me_gusta_programar_en_java_y_basededatos.";
char[] cadenaInicio = new char[cadena.length() - 15];
char[] cadenaFin = new char[15];
for (int i = 15; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
    cadenaInicio[i - 15] = cadena.charAt(i);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    cadenaFin[14 - i] = cadena.charAt(i);
}
String nuevaCadena = new String(cadenaInicio) + " " + new String(cadenaFin);
System.out.println(nuevaCadena);
```

Comment: El planteamiento es el correcto. Solo un pequeño detalle: para que se obtenga el mismo resultado esperado por OP, la cadena de tiene que acabar en un "." y habría que añadir un espacio en blanco entre la concatenación del substring y del reverse.

Comment: @ordago Tienes razón. Creo que no estaba así en su pregunta original. Editado. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @JonathanOrtiz Te dejo la nueva respuesta. Deberías editar tu pregunta para que recoja todo lo que pides, lo de los arrays incluido. Además, para la próxima vez, recuerda que siempre debes añadir qué has probado hasta el momento, el código que llevas hecho.